# Создание экземпляра класса ссылающегося на другой класс

Tags: c#, ооп

Добрый день, подскажите пожалуйста насчет следующего.
Допустим есть два класса

`MyClassA, MyClassB`
и код

```
MyClassA obj = new MyClassB();
```

в каких случаях такая запись справедлива?

Или задавая более конкретно вопрос, каким образом создать экземпляр obj который будет принадлежать типу MyClassA, но ссылаться на MyClassB ?
И продолжая вопрос, в экземпляре существуют все поля, методы и тд с обоих классов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MyClassA obj = new MyClassB();
```

Такая запись будет справедлива, если у Вас MyClassB наследуется от MyClassA

```
public class MyClassA
  {
     public void SetData()
     {
     }
  }


public class MyClassB: MyClassA
  {
     public void SetDataClassB()
     {
     }
  }
```

> Или задавая более конкретно вопрос, каким образом создать экземпляр obj который будет принадлежать типу MyClassA, но ссылаться на MyClassB ?

Вроде наследование подойдет, как я выше написал.

> И продолжая вопрос, в экземпляре существуют все поля, методы и тд с обоих классов?

Если пойдёте способом который я указал, то в obj Вы увидите только методы и свойства класса MyClassA, а для того что бы использовать методы свойства обоих классов необходимо будет сделать приведение obj к  MyClassB:

```
((MyClassB) obj).SetDataClassB();
```

либо так:

```
var obj1 = (MyClassB)obj;
obj1.SetDataClassB();
```

Comment: Для чего может использоваться такой случай? Кажись понял, когда методы могут перезагрузить (virtual, override) к примеру.

Answer (score 1):

Если один класс наследуется от другого, или реализует его (если это интерфейс).

Примеры:

1) Наследование.

```
public class MyClassA {
   [...]
}

public class MyClassB :MyClassA {
   [...]
}
```

2) Реализация интерфейса.

```
interface MyClassA {
   void MyMethod();
   [...]
}

public class MyClassB : MyClassA {
   public void MyMethod(){
   }

   [...]
}
```